# json encoded data to datatables

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatable

I have this json encoded data using 'server-side' version of datatables.
But how do I throw this value in datatables so my data could be listed in tabular format?

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"40","iTotalDisplayRecords":"40","aaData":[["test@test.com","5656565","656565"],["test@test.com","5656565","656565"],["test@test.com","5656565","656565"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","656","56"],["test@test.com","656","56"],["test@test.com","656","56"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["test@test.com","56565","56565"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","Lucknow","226005"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","Lucknow","226005"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","ko","koko"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","ko","koko"],["rahul_mishra@gmail.com","Greater Noida","201308"],["test@test.com","Lucknow","226005"],["znet@gmail.com","o","ok"],["znet@gmail.com","TA","TA"],["znet@gmail.com","Lucknow","226012"],["znet@gmail.com","Lucknow","226012"],["znet@gmail.com","Lucknow","226012"],["test@test.com","o","ok"],["test@test.com","o","ok"]]}
```

Comment: question makes no sense, doesn't a table constitute `tabular format`?

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't. There's no table, only the json is echoed.

Comment: what part of the documented plugin methods aren't working then?

Comment: It only throws in the required jSON data.

Comment: that is not a proper explanation of a problem...in fact the last comment is really meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load it through AJAX. Look at the example on the jQuery DataTables site.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html

You're going to have your server side script that outputs the data you posted. You will have some JS that makes an AJAX call to the server side script. This will handle placing the data into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Will create an object with your data

you can also create an array but uusing true as the second argument

```
$array= json_decode($json, true);
```